# Anyone using Microsoft ASML language?

Tags: .net, asml

To me the concept of "Gurevich Abstract State Machine" (formerly known as "evolving algebras") seems very promising to provide a solid fundation to systems behaviours. It could be what relational algebra is for databases: the underlying theoretic fundation.

The most complete implementation, to my knowledge, is the Microsoft **[ASML](http://research.microsoft.com/fse/asml/)** language that produces .NET assemblies.

Is anyone really using it in a working context? And, in case, with what degree of success?

I would really like to start investigating more, if others have success stories to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it several years back, but it seemed the project became stale. It is a pity, as I kinda liked it.